# format number in pascal by counting from 001

Tags: pascal

I am developing an app that assign registration number automatically to students.

How can I format "1" as "001" I.e to start counting from 001 not 1
For example:

```
Ubah david: 14/CSC/001
.....
Obi emeka : 14/CSC/122
```

Comment: This is highly depending on exact compiler. Most delphi compatibles have a "format"  function in sysutils

Answer (score 1):

Use [Format](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.Format). (The link is to Delphi 10 Seattle documentation, but the function hasn't changed in years. The function is in the SysUtils unit in all Delphi versions (since 1.0) and in [FreePascal](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/current/rtl/sysutils/format.html), and is available in most other modern Pascal dialects as well.)

```
for i := 1 to 10 do
  WriteLn(Format('%.3d', i));
ReadLn;
```

The format specifier has multiple parts (*%* followed by an optional *index:*, an optional left justification indicator *-*, an optional *width*, and an optional *.precision*, followed by a type indicator.

The `%d` means

> Decimal. The argument must be an integer value. The value is converted to a string of decimal digits. If the format string contains a precision specifier, it indicates that the resulting string must contain at least the specified number of digits; if the value has less digits, the resulting string is left-padded with zeros.

You can pass in the index, width and precision values directly (as the example above does), or indirectly using an asterisk (star, or `*`) as a placeholder. (See below for an example of doing this for the *precision* portion.)

So putting those together in the example above, you get an integer value, with a width of at least 3 (the precision), left padded with zeros:

```
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
010
```

So to put it together in a function for you:

```
function ZeroPad(const Value: Integer; const Width: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := Format('%.*d', [Width, Value]);
end;
```

Sample call:

```
for i := 1 to 10 do
  WriteLn(ZeroPad(i, 3));
ReadLn;
```

Comment: Ken, I guess, the OP has Pascal. See the tag.

Comment: Ken White .. pls  this code displays from 117 to 140 and omit 001 to116                for i := 1 to 140 do
  WriteLn(ZeroPad(i,3));
ReadLn;............................................................................................................................................................................................................................pls whats wrong with the code

Comment: @asd-tm: This code works fine in Pascal (FreePascal, Delphi, and TurboPascal). I merely provided the link to Delphi documentation because it's easy to find; the same code works fine in other Pascal flavors, and the documentation applies to them as well.

Comment: @DavidSharp: This code displays exactly the output I included (I copied/pasted it from the console window). The missing numbers are probably scrolling off the top of the console. Change the loop to `for i := 1 to 140 do begin ZeroPad(i, 3); if i mod 25 = 0 then ReadLn; end; ReadLn;` and see if you see the lower numbers.

Comment: Sorry; my mistake. `for i := 1 to 140 do begin WriteLn(ZeroPad(i, 3)); if  (i mod 25) = 0 then ReadLn; end; ReadLn;` should work. (The first forgot the WriteLn() around ZeroPad().)

Comment: I have just investigated: Googling  on `pascal functions and procedures list` gave me this [result](http://pascal.net.ru/functions+procedures+E-F+(en)) Borland Pascal did not posess this function.

Comment: I also did not find it on [this](http://pascal.sources.ru/tmt/help/strings_proc_and_func.htm) and [this](http://pascal.sources.ru/tmt/help/system_proc_and_func.htm) lists. However, no doubt the modern pascal dialects may have `format` function, but can we actually consider them as a _standard_ Pascal?

Comment: @asd-tm: The poster has said (in the comments to my answer) that it compiles and runs. The discussion over whether it was included in  antiquated Pascal dialects is only relevant if the poster is using one of them, which clearly is not the case. :-)

Comment: Probably the question requires retag then. Because there was no SysUtils unit in standard Pascal. It seems it appeared only in Delphi and then reintroduced in other dialects. By the way. The format function was absent in Turbo Pascal [also](http://www.eynak.com/bsu/TPProcFunc.pdf). I do not know the Arab language but the contents is clear.

Comment: @asd-tm: It's not mine to retag. I don't know what Pascal dialect the poster is using (and you should be commenting to ask the OP instead of discussing it with me). The OP indicates my code compiles and runs, so once again, the discussion is not relevant. Delphi and FreePascal are both Pascal dialects, and the question does not say *ancient Pascal dialect* or *Borland Pascal* or anything else. Discuss the specific version with the OP, and ask that they retag if necessary. I'm not aware of any *modern* Pascal dialect that doesn't contain Format().

Comment: asd-tm: standard pascal doesn't even have a string type, borland pascal is not standard pascal. Not even close.  Borland Pascal is mode "TP" in FPC, standard pascal is mode ISO. Standard pascal string type is like old C's, static arrays, though usually they used space padding instead of zero termination. Borland Pascal has a formatstr in Turbo Vision iirc, but it is not 100% compatible to Delphi's

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function GetFullNumber(n: word): string;
  begin
    str(n, result);
    while Length(result) < 3 do
      result := '0' + result;
  end;
```

Or add another parameter: the number of digits:

```
program Project1;

function GetFullNumber(const n, Digits: word): string;
begin
  str(n, result);
  while Length(result) < Digits do
    result := '0' + result;
end;

begin
  Writeln(GetFullNumber(3, 4));
  readln;
end.
```

**APPENDED**

If `result` reserved word is not supported by your Pascal compiler then replace it with the function name.

```
function GetFullNumber(const n, Digits: word): string;
begin
  str(n, GetFullNumber);
  while Length(GetFullNumber) < Digits do
    GetFullNumber := '0' + GetFullNumber;
end;
```

Comment: result is delphi, string and "word" is TP/Delphi. Standard pascal only has integer.